# Filter already requested data

Tags: php, laravel

There is a function which returns all tickets. I have two roles: `1-Moderator`(can see all tickets), `2-Client`(can see own tickets). So I request all tickets, then I check if `user` is `client`, then I need to filter out and show his own tickets. `Ticket` has `user_id` field. I think i can do with `foreach` or there is a better option?

```
$tickets = Ticket::all();
// check whether authenticated user is client
if (auth()->user()->role_id == 2) {

}

return new TicketsResourceCollection($tickets);
```

Comment: Don't you think it will be good if you fetch tickets direct on role basis, it will also optimise the records a bit if it is client.

Comment: @urfusion do you mean ```if (client) else if (moderator)```?

Comment: you can use where condition instead of `if/else`  for example `Ticket::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();`

Comment: you can use @amit-senjaliya  answer.

Comment: @DanabekDuisekov If moderator role id is `1` then do not filter ticket else filter by `use_id`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly filter out data using `user_id`:

```
if (auth()->user()->role_id == 1) {
    $tickets = Ticket::all();
} else {
    $tickets = Ticket::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you can use [Laravel Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#local-scopes) for that, you can write code in your Ticket model like this :

```
public function scopeClient($query)
{
    return $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
}
```

Then you can call your ticket that already scoped like this :

```
Ticket::client();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get tickets filtering by client_id or whatever or get all tickets.

```
        if (auth()->user()->role_id == 2) {
            $tickets = Ticket::where('client_id', auth()->user()->id )->get();
        }
        else {
            $tickets = Ticket::all();
        }

        return new TicketsResourceCollection($tickets);
```